# Why is Resharper breaking line after method opening brace and how to prevent it?

Tags: c#, resharper

I've been using Resharper 2016 with Visual Studio 2015, and I had code formatted like this:

```
list.Add(new SomeClass
{
    Value = 1,
    Name = "some name"
});
```

And life was beautiful...

But after updating to Visual Studio 2017, and to Resharper 2018, suddenly after hitting ctrl + E + C, and performing built-in R# option "Reformat code", I got this:

```
list.Add(
    new SomeClass
    {
        Value = 1,
        Name = "some name"
    });
```

Which is terrible, because I usually want indentation only after `{`.
The only exception being single line statement like 1-liner if, where I sometimes skip the curly brace but still have indentation.

**I've tried to switch all possible R# options to "simple wrap" but it didn't help. I've tried to set different values, where it made sense for me, but still no success.**

**Only after switching "revert to old formatting engine" it helped, but it also break other things, so that is not a viable solution for me.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select code and invoke with Alt+Enter "Format selection -> Configure", you'll see list of settings which affect formatting of this selection.
If you still have problems, you can reset settings in menu "ReSharper->Manage Options"
p.s. try uncheck "Line breacks and wrapping -> Arrangement of initializers -> prefer wrap after ( in invocation"

Comment: Unchecking "prefer wrap after `(` in invocation" did it for me! Also selecting the whole example code, and hitting "alt+enter -> format selection -> configure" is brilliant! Didn't know about it!

Comment: Great! More docs for formatting you can find [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html)